# ScrollArea and TabWidget resizing

Tags: c++, qt, resize, tabwidget

I am having trouble with my app. I am not able to configure wigets to behave acording to my needs, I would appreciate help.

This is “sketch” of my real app
http://s13.postimage.org/ibzzdh3p3/tab_Widget.png

So the main widget of MainWindow is scrollArea.
ScrollArea has vertical layout and contains 3 items.
1. Is big button, which represents constant sized area in my real app
2. Is spacer
3. TabWidget, has layouts on both tabs.

Now my problem. I am putting dynamically content into those tabs and I expect that if tab content cannot fit the tab than it will expand TabWidget in the scroll area.

Now it is filling space right when it fits the place, nice spacing and so. But if I fill it with lets say more lines(height 600px), than I can see the lines dissapearing somewhere down the tab and if I expand whole window TabWidget gets more space and more of my hiden widgets gets revealed.

Any ideas how can I force the content of the tabwidget to expand it rather then hide under?